# Local Dev <subtheme>.theme file not loading

Tags: 8, theming

I'm working on a local development environment (via Acquia Dev Desktop).  Our theme is a subtheme of the Stack theme.

In this situation, I'm making changes to my .theme file, but they don't seem to be loading at all.  If I make the same changes to the stack.theme, they load and work as expected.

I've ensured I'm using function `<subtheme>_theme_suggestions_page_alter` but still no luck.  There is nothing in the error.log either.

Comment: Please, check if you have setted your sub-theme correctly according https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme . Especially check availability a string base theme: <your core theme machine name here>
in your-theme.info.yml .

Comment: Have you tried clearing your local cache? If you are looking for ways to troubleshoot, have you tried printing an HTML tag to the page or adding a log message using [Drupal Watchdog](https://drupalize.me/blog/201510/how-log-messages-drupal-8) in your page alter hook? This way you can log something like "hook ran" to see if it runs by checking your Watchdog log messages.

Comment: Not sure if it was the cache, but per @V.Vil the sub-theme was setup correctly.  I'd already tried clearing the caches, but no luck.  I downloaded a fresh copy of the database from the Acquia environment, cleared the caches again, and it started working.

Comment: @JMichael in some situations i had to clear cache if i created a new hook. Updates tending to show up. Additional local setting can be https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Answer (score 5):

Got it fixed on my local environment by putting the base theme name in quotes and then clearing the cache.

Changed `base theme: classy` to `base theme: "classy"`.

Also, check for a single quote on your theme's description. If you find it, make sure you put the whole description in quotes.

Comment: No need of quotes. It should work without quotes as well.

Comment: Can confirm this fixed an issue in my theme. Haven't dug into why, but it had me scratching my head when my preprocess function wasn't firing... sure enough, I had classy without quotes as the base theme.

Comment: Thank you . This helped me to get my .theme file recognized. Without the double quotes the .theme file is ignored!
I do not understand why. Is there any official Drupal issue about this?

Comment: Quotes don't make a difference, but trailing whitespaces do! In Yaml something like `key:value` is the same as `key:   value`, but `key:value    ` is NOT the same same as `key:value`

Comment: Thank you! My .theme file only started loading after putting classy in quotes (single quotes)! Weird. After getting it to load I could remove the quotes and it still works, so the actual mechanism must be something else.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to solve my problem!

Comment: Adding the quotes fixed it for me... yup, this is Drupal. Thanks so much.